# Warning in XMPP classes on iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, xmpp, ios6, xmppframework

I am getting multiple warnings when I am trying to run my XMPP chat client on iOS 6

```
'dispatch_get_current_queue' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0
```

Not sure how to fix these warnings. Is updated XMPP framework available for objective C compatible with iOS 6?

Comment: It might be. Have you checked the XMPP website?

Comment: You can still use it. It is just deprecated.

Comment: @adamjansch XMPP framework for Objective C has been written by Robbie Hanson. I checked his github page but no updates yet.

Comment: @Paul de Lange That is correct but still there should be some way to overcome these warnings

Comment: Then probably best to contact Robbie Hanson about future updates. Just live with the warnings for now.

Comment: @adamjansch Yeah did that, sent an email over XMPP support group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was reported at the project page:

- https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/115
- https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/pull/140

Someone uploaded a patch. Either give that a try, or just live with the warning until the patch is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the warning in the XMPPFramework with this line:

NSAssert(dispatch_get_specific(moduleQueueTag), @"Invoked on incorrect queue");